# How can I create the virtual table using FTS in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, android-sqlite, fts3, fts4

How can I create the **virtual table using FTS in SQLite.**

I have 3 tables, but I don't want to add the columns manually into the table.

For example: I have the 3 tables
 like: `t1(t1_id,t1_name)`, `t2(t2_id,t2_name)`, `t3(t3_id,t1_id,t2_id,t3_name)`

Now, I want to create virtual table in which I  want to give only t3 and 
the columns in t1 and t2 should automatically map into the virtual table.

The expected output should be:-

```
 virtualTable(vt1,t3_id,t3_name,t2_id,t2_name,t1_id,t1_name)
```

I refer [this](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) and [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=FullTextIndex) links, but I didn't find the solution for my question

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your code to contain your attempts to solve the problem and what results / errors you received.